# cygwin win 8.1 error: find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer

Tags: cygwin, x11

This error has occurred some time ago, in 2011
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-11/msg00021.html

From what I have read on this and some other posts,
I see that they have written some ugly hack which parses a windows dll looking for this
FAST_CWD variable.
My best guess is that a newer windows update has again changed the dll and now the function is broken again.

I am not familiar with the skills used while developing cygwin so I only guess on these things.

Any suggestions?

Also, maybe this log might shed some light:

```
Dito@Kungi ~
$ serverx11
-bash: serverx11: command not found

Dito@Kungi ~
$ startx11

Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.15.0.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.3 Kungi 1.7.28(0.271/5/3) 2014-02-09 21:06 x86_64
OS: Windows 8.1  [Windows NT 6.3 build 9600](Win64)
Package: version 1.15.0-4 built 2014-03-27

XWin was started with the following command line:

X :0 -multiwindow

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension GLX
(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/Dito/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw installed, allowing ShadowDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - Windows NT, allowing PrimaryDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 0000001f
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1440 height: 900 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
winInitMultiWindowWM - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shar                                                                                                                           ed memory support in the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
GL_VERSION:     1.1.0
GL_VENDOR:      Microsoft Corporation
GL_RENDERER:    GDI Generic
wglwrap: Can't resolve "wglGetExtensionsStringARB"
(EE) AIGLX: Won't use generic native renderer as it is not accelerated
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygGL-1.dll'
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
(II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
(II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 720 450
(--) 8 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "0000041A" (0000041a) "Croatian", type 7
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "Croatian"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "hr" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "hr" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
winBlockHandler - pthread_mutex_unlock()
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winInitMultiWindowWM - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the disp                                                                                                                           lay.
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.

Dito@Kungi ~
$ winMultiWindowXMsgProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the                                                                                                                            display.


Dito@Kungi ~
$ xcompas
      2 [main] xcompas 5796 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD po                                                                                                                           inter.  Please report this problem to
the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/bin/xanchor.exe: error while loading shared libra                                                                                                                           ries: libXpm.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
xcompas: DISPLAY environment variable is not set
Set DISPLAY environment variable
```

Answer (score 0):

This generally means you need to update Cygwin, at this point they likely have fixed it long ago.

Comment: The fix to cygwin should be older than win8.1.  A cygwin version that old is almost certain to be problematical, and not susceptible to any credible response here other than to update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem and answer is:

Actually the default compiler GCC in its version GCC3.2 cannot be used under windows 10.

There are two alternatives:

- Using GCC version 3.2 : supported up to windows 8.1
- Using GCC version 4.4 : supported by Windows 7, 8 and 10.

The GCC toolchain available since a quite long time now was based on GCC3.2 compiler. It now comes with the next release GCC4.4.

For different reasons it might be useful to use GCC4.4 instead of GCC3.2.

1. GCC3.2 is not supported by Windows 10 and next coming Windows operation system
2. GCC3.2 maintenance is frozen.
3. All bug fixes and new features will only appear in upgrades of GCC version 4.4 (4.x, 5.x, etc.).
4. GCC4.4 offers some better optimization results (typically from 10 to 15% less code footprint produced)

Thanks to only few modifications (hopefully) in your project to comply with GCC4.4 you can port your firmware your from GCC3.2 to GCC4.4.

Most aspects of the modifications are explained in this attached document “Raisonance tools for C816 family – Getting Started” document [GettingStartedC816_Ride7.pdf file] in chapter 4.4. This file is also located under \Raisonance \Ride\Doc\C816 folder.

I also add in attach a technical note (and its project source code) I wrote which summarizes the common changes to be applied. It is based on a specific firmware call “beacon” but as an example i guess it can be useful for a lot of ones.

So in case Win10 is a must,  I recommend that you:

- update your firmware to GCC4.2. Let me know if you need assistance
- run a short validation to make sure that the functionality is not modified by the new compilation.

link : http://support.raisonance.com/content/gcc-c816-error-couldnt-compute-fastcwd-pointer

Comment: $ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin